# What's "terms of order" in math?

Tags: mathematics

There are descriptions in the [book](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=o_Pjbo4Wvp8C&pg=PA33&dq=%22it%20was%20in%20state%20i%20at%20time%20t%20and%20has%20not%20moved%20during%20the%20time%20interval%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj08t_Q4vDQAhWHj5QKHYYHBVoQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22it%20was%20in%20state%20i%20at%20time%20t%20and%20has%20not%20moved%20during%20the%20time%20interval%22&f=false):

> This event has a probability of Pi(t)(1 −λit) plus terms of order t2.

What's "terms of order" here?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mathematical terminology.

Comment: It's not grouped (terms of order) (t2), it's (terms of) (order t2). You would have to look at the meaning "order t2" in that context, but it likely means "some function of t2". The implication is usually that those terms are either negligible in practice, or not necessary for the proof.

Comment: "[This tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics) is for questions about the usage and meaning of mathematical terminology and the names for mathematical entities in English." This is by the tag's own description, ON TOPIC.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, order refers to the power of the terms, specifically terms in t squared. The term order has other uses in different branches of mathematics. – Mick

Comment: Do you have any supporting evidence? Although it's flattering, I'm hardly an authority.

Comment: @Mick -it looks like an informed answer and you sound like you know what you are saying.

Comment: @Mick I agree with JOSH. In this case one would use *order* when t is small to indicate that (1 −λit) is good approximation of what's inside the parentheses when t goes to zero. It should be written [1 −λit+O(t**2)], where ** denotes squared.